# serialize data to ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),default=list) field

Tags: json, django, serialization

I have the following field in postgres database :ArrayField(models.IntegerField(),default=list).

When I send data from post request I get the following error:
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[176,68]'

while the data sent is price:[176,68]
Here is my serializer for price :

```
class StringArrayField(ListField):
    """
    String representation of an array field.
    """
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        obj = super().to_representation( obj)
        # convert list to string
        return ",".join([(element) for element in obj])

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return super().to_internal_value( data)


class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    price = StringArrayField()

    class Meta:
        model = myModel
        fields =('price')
```

Answer (score 1):

You must pass a `child` serializer to the listfield.

```
price = serializers.ListField(
   child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=100)
)
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean I shoud do this :
    price = serializers.ListField( child=serializers.IntegerField(min_value=0, max_value=100)  )  instead of price = StringArrayField() ??

Comment: Yes. You don't need to define a `StringArrayField`, but if you really need to override any methods, you should read and understand the [source code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L1575) of the parent class `ListField`. I couldn't make any sense of your current `StringArrayField` code.